# Difference between decryption and deciphering?

Tags: encryption, terminology

Is there a technical difference between decryption and deciphering?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no actual technical difference, but it's sometimes used in different contexts.

**Decryption:** Used when talking about reversing an encryption of any type and when you *know* for sure that a message has been encrypted.

**Deciphering**: Used when (mostly) turning a *ciphertext* back to the plaintext, i.e. when a sentence has been encrypted with some sort of cipher like for example [Caesar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher) or [Vigenère](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher). It's also appropriate to use this term if people *assume* that a message has been encrypted or obfuscated.